# htaccess redirect entire website except the wordpress backend

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the entire wordpress website to another domain, but want to be able to access the dashboard.

Here is what I've tried :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule http://thisdomain.com/wp-admin/ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can do some updates in this rule and use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923064/redirect-visitors-to-new-url-but-exclude-images-and-admin

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your rules. try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thisdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Majid , but this gives me Internal Server Error

Comment: try it now, there was an extra space copy and paste again and let me know

Comment: thisdomain.com/wp-admin still redirects to newdomain

Comment: just update again sorry I forgot to delete $1 at the end of the new domain. Try again , I have tested locally and it's working now.thanks