# htaccess multiple conditions for re-write rule for wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have the following rule in the `.htaccess` file for redirecting my Wordpress blog to a maintenance page.

```
#Redirecting to maintenance page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blogs/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-domain.com/blogs/maintenance.html [R=307, L]
```

This is working fine and all the pages are re-directed to the maintenance page. Now I need to add `wp-admin` to the condition so that I will be able to login to the admin side. I have tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blogs/maintenance\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blogs/wp-admin/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-domain/blogs/maintenance.html [R=307, L]
```

But this is not working and the `wp-admin` is redirected to maintenance page.

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923064/redirect-visitors-to-new-url-but-exclude-images-and-admin

Comment: I added this, but now the `wp-admin` is also redirecting maintenance page `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blogs/maintenance\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blogs/wp-admin/$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blogs/maintenance\.html$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blogs/wp-admin/$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blogs/maintenance.html [R=307, L]
> ```

There are several errors here (and in your original rule):

- The value of the `REQUEST_URI` server variable starts with a slash, so the first (and second) *condition* is always going to be successful. (But this would have resulted in a redirect loop - unless you've put the rule in the wrong place at the end of the `.htaccess` file??)
- You have included an end-of-string anchor on the second *condition* (ie. `!^blogs/wp-admin/$`) so it's only going to match that exact URL. You need to prevent the maintenance page from being displayed for any URL that *starts with* `/blogs/wp-admin/`.
- You have a *space* in the flags argument, ie. `[R=307, L]`. This is syntactically invalid and would have broken with a 500 error (which I assume it wasn't, but how?)

So, it should be something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogs/wp-admin(/|$)
RewriteRule !^blogs/maintenance\.html$ https://www.example.com/blogs/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

And this should go at the top of the `.htaccess` file.

You'll also need to exclude any other assets (and AJAX requests) that your admin pages or maintenance page are using.

I've moved the first condition to the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Note that the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against does *not* start with a slash.

---

**Aside:**

HOWEVER, you should not be *redirecting* the request to serve an "under maintenance" page. Serve a "503 Service Unavailable" response directly instead and ideally a `Retry-After` HTTP response header to inform search engines when to resume crawling. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /blogs/maintenance.html

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blogs/wp-admin(/|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [R=503]

Header always set Retry-After "Mon, 15 Mar 2023 19:00:00 GMT"
```

This serves the 503 response as an internal subrequest, there is no external redirect (2nd request). The `maintenance.html` document is not exposed to the end user as the URL does not change. By checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable we can also send a 503 response for direct requests to the `maintenance.html` document itself.